# Find the points on two line segments that are exactly r units apart

Tags: geometry

I am trying to use this technique in order to find the collision point of a fast moving 2D circle and a line segment. Because the circle is fast moving I only know it’s start and end point but the collision may have happened somewhere between the two. The thought is that at the point where the fast moving circle intersects with the line the distance between the circles center (and thus a point on the particles movement line) will be `r`.

This is sort of a derivative of the formula where you are finding the closest points between two lines. However in this case you are trying to find the points that are `r` units apart.

I can’t figure out how to even begin solving this.

Keep in mind these are line segments and both lines do have endpoints.

I do realize there could be a number of outcomes from this formula including cases where there are 2 sets of points that are r units apart.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which technique are you talking about?

Comment: There’s this to find the closest point http://morroworks.palitri.com/Content/Docs/Rays%20closest%20point.pdf and this technique here for just the intersection https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/3833632